# How to reply to a business email with "yes, I'm ok with this time frame"?

Tags: keigo, business-japanese, email

So I received an email from one of our suppliers who aims to visit my company and have a meeting with me, the main part of it is

> 12月5日(金)13時以降にご都合は如何でしょうか？

Now, I am fine with the mentioned date/time, and I would like to reply in a bit formal way.

My attempts are like:

> 1. はい、12月5日(金)13時以降にご都合大丈夫です。
> 2. 12月5日(金)13時以降に来ていただいても宜しいです。

But they still don't seem to be really formal, and may even sound offensive somehow?!

P.S: I do speak Japanese without any problem, but still struggle when it comes to business emails, and 敬語 :(

Comment: I see problems with (1) and (2), so I would wait for an answer. (Though you don't want any suggestions from me, I hardly know what I'm doing. :-)

Comment: Google “ご都合はいかがでしょうか 返信”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ご都合 is an honorific expression, so don't use ご都合 if it refers to the 都合 of yourself.
- よろしいです [sounds like you were higher than the guest](http://bizkeigo.koakishiki.com/question/question-8.html). ("よろしいでしょうか" is OK, though)

My suggestion:

- 12月5日(金)13時以降であれば差し支えありません。
- 12月5日(金)13時以降にお越しいただければ問題ありません。
- 12月5日(金)13時以降であれば、こちらの都合は大丈夫です。(maybe too verbose)

Comment: how about the combination: お越し頂ければ差し支えありません。? doesn't it sound too exaggerating ?

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree with the suggestion that you can't use 都合 to describe your own circumstances. For example --as you'll no doubt concur-- this is perfect Japanese: "申し訳ありませんが、こちらの経理処理の都合上、できましたら11月10日までにお知らせいただければと思います。"　Perhaps it's a typo, and you mean don't use "**ご**都合 of yourself"?

Comment: @Will I'm not sure it was a typo, but edited anyway. Is this OK now?

Comment: @chouaib Okay, but I don't use it because it sounds a bit too wordy.

Comment: @naruto: yes, that looks good now.